# Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#

I am having issues with the following code. I am iterating through a set to see if an object has a certain property type and if so, do some conversion to it.

```
var props = obj.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var p in props)
{     
    if (p.PropertyType == typeof(System.Boolean))
    {
    var conv = Convert.ToByte(p);
    }
}
```

I get the following error when I try to run it:

"Unable to cast object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo' to type 'System.IConvertible'."

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to get the value of the property and convert *that* to a byte, right? Not the property itself... so:

```
var conv = Convert.ToByte(p.GetValue(obj, null));
```

It seems odd to have it as a `byte` rather than a `bool`, admittedly... I'd have expected:

```
var conv = (bool) p.GetValue(obj, null);
```

I'd also personally use:

```
if (p.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
```

rather than spelling out the `System.Boolean` explicitly.